# .png files in .rc (resource file)

Tags: winapi, qt, resources

I use .png files inside my Qt application, but to make ico for .exe file, i need use .ico,

```
IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE     "app.ico"
```

can I put app.png instead of app.ico?

Comment: why png? you can easily convert to ico...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can't. I took a quick glance over the Qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/appicon.html) regarding application icon's and it seems that for Windows you must use .ico filetype.